# when ReportRun.run() execute, operation finish AX2012

Tags: report, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I want to attach a report in e-mail. Format of report is PDF. And i use this code for save report with PDF format;

```
Args                args;
reportRun           reportRun;


args = new args();
args.name(reportStr("InventTransferShipReport"));
args.caller(this);
args.parm(transferId);
args.parmObject(setRecord);
args.menuItemName(menuitemOutputStr(InventTransferShipReport));

reportRun = new reportRun(args);
reportRun.init();
WinAPI::deleteFile("C:\\Temp\\Test.pdf");
reportRun.printJobSettings().setTarget(PrintMedium::File);
reportRun.printJobSettings().format(PrintFormat::PDF);
reportRun.printJobSettings().fileName("C:\\Temp\\Test.pdf");
reportRun.run();


if(WinAPI::fileExists("C:\\Temp\\Test.pdf"))
{
    info("done");
}
else
{
    info("error");
}
```

But when i debugging code i noticed that the process end when reportRun.run(); execute. So why? How can i fixed this issue?

Comment: Please double check your [report server setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/connect-microsoft-dynamics-ax-to-the-new-reporting-services-instance) and validate that the `InventTransferShipReport` report is properly deployed.

Comment: Are you sure this is for version R3? This code does not compile on my system. You probably want to use the report controller class instead to call the report.

Comment: thanks for your answers. @Sander report is not SSRS Report unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for your answer @FH-Inway what is your advice for R3 ?

Comment: As I wrote, try the report controller class (see [ssrsReportStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-compile-time-functions#ssrsreportstr)).